# Using map() in R to apply a list to function for web scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr

Here's my problem: I have this list I've generated containing a large number of links and I want to take this list and apply a function to it to scrape some data from all those links; however, when I run the program it only takes the data from the first link of that element, reprinting that info for the correct number of iterations. Here's all my code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

source_link<-"http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all"
source_link_html<-read_html(source_link)

#This scrapes all the links for the pages of all the fighters
links_vector<-source_link_html%>%
  html_nodes("div ul li a")%>%
  html_attr("href")%>%
  #This seq selects the 26 needed links, i.e. from a-z
  .[1:26]

#Modifies the pulled data so the links become useable and contain all the fighers instead of just some
links_vector_modded<-str_c("http://www.ufcstats.com", links_vector,"&page=all")

fighter_links<-sapply(links_vector_modded, function(links_vector_modded){
  read_html(links_vector_modded[])%>%
  html_nodes("tr td a")%>%
  html_attr("href")%>%
  .[seq(1,length(.),3)]%>%
  na.omit(fighter_links)
})

###Next Portion: Using the above links to further harvest

#Take all the links within an element of fighter_links and run it through the function career_data to scrape all the statistics from said pages.
fighter_profiles_a<-map(fighter_links$`http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a&page=all`, function(career_data){
  #Below is where I believe my problem lies
  read_html()%>%
  html_nodes("div ul li")%>%
  html_text() 
})
```

The issue I'm having is in the last section of code,`read_html()`. I do not know how to apply each link in the element within the list to that function. Additionally, is there a way to call all of the elements of `fighter_links` instead of doing it one element at a time?

Thank you for any advice and assistance!

Comment: if you do not need the newest data you could spare the scrapping by taking data from kaggle (fights and fighters): https://www.kaggle.com/rajeevw/ufcdata

Comment: Thank you, DPH, that's awesome! I'm definitely going to play around with that data. However, I'm doing this just as much for the data's sake as for learning R so I want to know how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unlist` to get all the `fighter_links` together and pass it to `map` function to extract relevant text.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

fighter_profiles_a<-map(unlist(fighter_links), function(career_data){
  read_html(career_data)%>%
    html_nodes("div ul li")%>%
    html_text() 
})
```

The text captured at `fighter_profiles_a` might require some additional cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that `fighter_links` is a list of vectors.  Applying `map` to each list element leaves you with a vector of URLs, and you want to get information from each URL.

If it's important to retain the structure of `fighter_links` - meaning, you don't lose which URL belongs to each fighter - you can nest your call to `map`, like this:

```r
fighter_profiles <- 
  fighter_links %>%
    map(function(url_list) {
      map(url_list,
           function(url) read_html("http://www.ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9"[]) %>% 
             html_nodes("div ul li") %>% 
             html_text() %>%
             str_replace_all(., "\n\\s+\n\\s+", "")) # a little clean up
    })
```

This produces nested output, which you can use to keep track of which `fighter_links` entry it came from:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1] "Height:--\n    "         "Weight:155 lbs.\n    "   "Reach:--\n    "          "STANCE:"                
 [5] "DOB:Jul 13, 1978"        "SLpM:0.00\n\n        "   "Str. Acc.:0%\n        "  "SApM:0.00\n        "    
 [9] "Str. Def:0%\n        "   ""                        "TD Avg.:0.00\n        "  "TD Acc.:0%\n        "   
[13] "TD Def.:0%\n        "    "Sub. Avg.:0.0\n        " "Events & Fights"         "Fighters"               
[17] "Stat Leaders"           

[[1]][[2]]
 [1] "Height:--\n    "         "Weight:155 lbs.\n    "   "Reach:--\n    "          "STANCE:"                
 [5] "DOB:Jul 13, 1978"        "SLpM:0.00\n\n        "   "Str. Acc.:0%\n        "  "SApM:0.00\n        "    
 [9] "Str. Def:0%\n        "   ""                        "TD Avg.:0.00\n        "  "TD Acc.:0%\n        "   
[13] "TD Def.:0%\n        "    "Sub. Avg.:0.0\n        " "Events & Fights"         "Fighters"               
[17] "Stat Leaders"
```

Note: You can use `map` instead of the initial `sapply` as well, if you like:

```r
path <- "http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters"
query_str <- paste0("?char=", letters, "&page=all")
urls <- paste0(path, query_str)

get_fighter_link <- function(url) {
  read_html(url[])%>%
    html_nodes("tr td a")%>%
    html_attr("href")%>%
    .[seq(1, length(.), 3)]%>%
    na.omit(fighter_links)
}

fighter_links <- map(urls, get_fighter_link)
```